# Red5 demos failing to run

Tags: windows, red5, red5-recorder

I am running Red5 1.0.7 on Windows 8. I am abke to start the server, but when I attempt to run a SimpleChat demo (http://localhost:5080/demos/SimpleChat.html) I get the following failure:

```
[WARN] [RTMPConnectionExecutor-1] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPHandler - Scope not found
org.red5.server.exception.ScopeNotFoundException: Scope not found: SOSample in null
    at org.red5.server.scope.ScopeResolver.resolveScope(ScopeResolver.java:112)
    at org.red5.server.Context.resolveScope(Context.java:158)
    at org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPHandler.onCommand(RTMPHandler.java:323)
    at org.red5.server.net.rtmp.BaseRTMPHandler.messageReceived(BaseRTMPHandler.java:116)
    at org.red5.server.net.rtmp.ReceivedMessageTask.call(ReceivedMessageTask.java:72)
    at org.red5.server.net.rtmp.ReceivedMessageTask.call(ReceivedMessageTask.java:38)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[INFO] [RTMPConnectionExecutor-1] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPHandler - Scope SOSample not found on localhost
[INFO] [RTMPConnectionExecutor-1] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPMinaConnection - Connection is closed: KG0TZJZBWYITN
```

In fact, I get similar errors when I attempt to run any demo application. For example, with the Bandwidth Check application (http://localhost:5080/demos/bwcheck.html):

```
[WARN] [RTMPConnectionExecutor-2] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPHandler - Scope not found
org.red5.server.exception.ScopeNotFoundException: Scope not found: bwcheck in null
    at org.red5.server.scope.ScopeResolver.resolveScope(ScopeResolver.java:112)
    at org.red5.server.Context.resolveScope(Context.java:158)
    at org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPHandler.onCommand(RTMPHandler.java:323)
    at org.red5.server.net.rtmp.BaseRTMPHandler.messageReceived(BaseRTMPHandler.java:116)
    at org.red5.server.net.rtmp.ReceivedMessageTask.call(ReceivedMessageTask.java:72)
    at org.red5.server.net.rtmp.ReceivedMessageTask.call(ReceivedMessageTask.java:38)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[INFO] [RTMPConnectionExecutor-2] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPHandler - scope bwcheck not found on localhost
[INFO] [RTMPConnectionExecutor-2] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPMinaConnection - Connection is closed: ZFUADXAXT2NQX
```

I had thought that there probably was a need to actually install these applications, so I tried running the installer (http://localhost:5080/installer/). When I start that, however, I don't see any applications in the list and on the server side I am getting the following:

```
[INFO] [RTMPConnectionExecutor-3] org.red5.server.adapter.ApplicationAdapter - W3C x-category:session x-event:connect c-ip:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 c-client-id:0
[WARN] [RTMPConnectionExecutor-4] org.red5.server.service.Installer - Service returned an error
```

There is clearly some kind of configuration or installation problem, but I cannot find it. Does anyone know what is causing these problems and how to fix them?

Please advise.

Comment: If ever you get `Scope not found: <someapp>`, open a file browser and look in your `red5/webapps` directory; you will most likely find that there is no directory named <someapp> there and if it is, its empty.

Comment: Also with the shutdown of googlecode services, the Red5 installer app needs extra configuration for some older releases. See my comment from May 27th https://github.com/Red5/red5-server/issues/180

Comment: Thanks for the info. The installer seems to be working now except that an attempt to install is generating a lot of exceptions. As for your info about the scope failures, these failures are occurring with demo applications(!) -- that is, the applications in webapps/root/demos folder. Are you saying that the free Red5 ships *without* the actual server- side code for applications like bwcheck (the demo bandwidth checker)??? If it does, where do I get this code???

Comment: Red5 has been around for 11 years, you will certainly find code that doesnt work on the internet. Much if not all the code can be searched for in github for instance https://github.com/search?q=org%3ARed5+bwcheck&type=Code

Comment: BTW another developer wrote the bwcheck app and the server-side source isn't in github; I'll see if I can find it and if I do, ill post it to github.

Comment: But Paul: The Red5 that I downloaded is from *the Red5 website*. I did not add or remove anything from the 1.0.7 distribution. At the very least, since people are actually putting out new versions, one would think that they would remove old, non- working code from the distribution. As it is, it looks like the latest release has a lot of non- working baggage whose only contribution to the release is the confusion that it causes...

Comment: Thanks in advance for the bwheck application (when you find it). I would be curious to look at an actual working demo so I can learn how to make any applications I create work.

Comment: True, there is probably some old stuff that can be curated. In the meantime you imply nothing works? Did you not see video play when you went to http://localhost:5080/ ? That's the first working example that one would see. Others that work would be OflaDemo and the SharedObject ball demo, both of which are installable via the installer. Lastly theres the chat demo, which is included.

Comment: I've added SOSample (no java code) and bwcheck to https://github.com/Red5/red5-examples